# Correct place of period

Tags: punctuation

Consider following that is followed by a parenthetical sentence. Which one is correct according to punctuation rules?

1. Xxx yyy zzz. (Aaa bbb ccc.)
2. Xxx yyy zzz (Aaa bbb ccc.).